# How do you deep copy a variant of pointers in C++?

Tags: c++, copy, deep-copy, variant

I have a `std::variant` whose alternatives are all pointers.

```cpp
class a {
  public:
    int* placeholder; 
    a(a& _copy) { /* Does a deep copy */ }
} 

class b {
  // For demonstrational purposes, identical to a.
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::variant<a*, b*>> instances = // initialise vector, guaranteed no nullptrs. 
}
```

Now, for instance, if I want to push a deep copy of the first element to the back, I cannot simply do `instances.push_back(instances[0])`, because that does a shallow copy of the `vector`.

Of course, the obvious solution would be to check for all alternatives, then `get_if`, create a copy, and return the copy. However, I think there has to be a better way. How should something as such be done?

I am also open to solutions that do not use variants.

Comment: Make sure all the variant's pointers are smart [value pointers](https://buckaroo.pm/blog/value-ptr-the-missing-smart-ptr).

Comment: Explicit code must be written to do all this work, based on `std::visit`, and adding the appropriate deep copy logic for each variant value. There's nothing in C++ that will do all this work, upon demand.

Comment: please dont post fantasy code. The code you posted has missing `;`, the copy constructor has wrong signature, `// For demonstrational purposes, identical to a.` comments are liars, `b` is not identical to `a`, `b` has no members. `/* Does a deep copy */` the actul code would be less than that comment. Consider that someone who wants to write an answer and compile and test it will have to add all the missing pieces to your code (before even starting to answer the quesiton). Please read about [mcve] and try to provide one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you can use `std::visit`. I strongly suggest to use smart pointers.

```
#include <variant>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    // init and print x    
    std::variant<std::unique_ptr<int>,std::unique_ptr<std::string>> x = std::make_unique<std::string>("foo"); 
    auto print = [](const auto& x) { std::cout << *x << "\n";};
    std::visit(print,x);

    // make the copy
    auto deep_copy = [](const auto& x) -> std::variant<std::unique_ptr<int>,std::unique_ptr<std::string>> {
         
        return std::make_unique<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*x)>>(*x); 
        // replace this creating a proper clone 
    };
    auto y = std::visit(deep_copy,x);    
    std::visit(print,y);
    
    // check that it actually is a deep copy
    auto modify = [](auto& x) { *x += 'a';};
    std::visit(modify,x);
    std::visit(print,x);
    std::visit(print,y);
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/dvnM4z7s7):

```
foo
foo
fooa
foo
```

I'll leave it to you to modify the code in case each variant requires a different way to copy. The above is the simple case where all types can be handled by a templated lambda. For the case of actually requiring distinct branches for each variant I refer you to documentation (eg https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit). Most importantly (as pointed out by user17732522 in their comment), this `std::make_unique<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*x)>>(*x)` is the wrong way to copy a `std::unique_ptr<Base>` managing a `Derived` instance.

Comment: `std::make_unique<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*x)>>` is generally not correct: Either the pointed-to types are polymorphic and then you are potentially slicing to a base class, or they aren't polymorphic and then there is likely no reason to use a pointer at all. (Of course OP didn't specify why the pointers are there...)

Comment: @user17732522 good point. I was just in the process of adding a note of what is missing. If they want to make porper polymorphic clone then of course the types in the variant must support that